# Count boolean field values within a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I like to get the amount of rows where a certain field is either 1 or 0.

My table looks like this:

```
ID | name | my_bool
===================
 1 | foo  | 1
 2 | bar  | 1
 3 | loo  | 0
 4 | zoo  | 1
```

as result I expect

```
YES | NO  | percentage
======================
 3  | 1   | 0.3333
```

`YES` is how many rows where `my_bool` is **true** (1) while `NO` is where rows with **false** (0)

`percentage` give the percentage of `YES` to `NO`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this easily with conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(my_bool = 1) as yes, sum(my_bool = 0) as no
from table t;
```

EDIT:

The percentage is very easy:

```
select sum(my_bool = 1) as yes, sum(my_bool = 0) as no, avg(my_bool = 0)
from table t;
```

However, your value suggests you are looking for a ratio, not a percentage.  For that, you need to be careful about divide by zero:

```
select sum(my_bool = 1) as yes, sum(my_bool = 0) as no,
       (case when sum(my_bool = 1) > 0 then sum(my_bool = 0) / sum(my_bool = 1)
        end)
from table t;
```

Comment: dividing by zero returns NULL which can be handled in my application. Does this cause any problems though? I use PHP's `floatval`which returns `0`

Comment: I prefer to do explicit error checking for things like "divide by zero".  The behavior is controlled by a system variable, so someone could decide to change the default on your system -- and break all the code.

Comment: Thanks, most valuable answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(my_bool=1, 1, 0)) AS YES, SUM(IF(my_bool=0, 1, 0)) AS NO
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select
    count(foo.my_bool) as "YES",
    count(bar.my_bool) as "NO",
    (count(bar.my_bool) / count(foo.mybool)) as "percentage"
from
    myTable foo
    left join myTable bar
        on foo.id = bar.id
where
    foo.my_bool = 1
    and bar.my_bool = 0
```

*Edit: Be sure to prevent division by zero as mentioned by Gordon Linoff.*

Comment: No, the name column has nothing todo with the boolean

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I didn't reference the name column. I simply used the traditional "foo" and "bar" as alias names for the suggestion of joining the table on itself.

Comment: ok, sorry my fault, can you make an edit so I can update the downvote

Comment: `COUNT(field)` does not count the number of true values.  It counts the number of non-NULL values.  If the field is a `BOOLEAN NOT NULL`, or simply doesn't have any `NULL` values, as seems to be the case here, then `COUNT(field)` will not do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT sum(my_bool) AS Yes, count(ID)-sum(my_bool) AS No FROM mytable
```